# Как установить svg фон по id

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть  такой SVG код, который я пытаюсь добавить в HTML с помощью свойства CSS -`background`

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(#bg);
}

#curvestroke {
  fill: red;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>

<svg id="bg">
  <defs>
    <path id='curvestroke' d="M0,0 C100,70 500,50 0,500"></path>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Почему у div нет фона?

Comment: Я не знаю так вообще можно? `background: url(#bg);` . В первый раз вижу.

Comment: Можно я использовал

Comment: можно такой рабочий пример увидеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду вы добавляете код svg **инлайн** в Html страничку.
В этом случае при повторном использовании его в различных местах html должна использоваться команда `<use>`

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  
}

#curvestroke {
  fill: red;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <path id='curvestroke' d="M0,0 C100,70 500,50 0,500"></path>
  </defs>
</svg>
    <div>
        <svg>
         <use xlink:href="#curvestroke"/>
        </svg>
    
    </div>
```

**Добавление svg с помощью background**

В этом случае код svg находится в отдельном файле и для его использования  необходимо указать путь и имя файла svg.

**CSS**

```
button.icon-plus{ background: url(http://dahlström.net/svg-icon-target.svg);}
```

Если в одном файле SVG несколько изображений используются их `ID  (#)`

```
button.icon-plus { background: url(http://dahlström.net/svg-icon-target.svg#plus); }
button.icon-chart { background: url(http://dahlström.net/svg-icon-target.svg#chart); }
```

Ниже рабочий пример от @erikdahlstrom, где используются две техники добавления svg с помощью правил css `background` и с использовнием тега `<img>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Animated SVG-gradient</title>
  <style>
  html { padding: 50px; }

button {
    width:  32px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button.icon-plus { background: url(http://dahlström.net/tmp/sharp-icons/svg-icon-target.svg#plus) no-repeat; }
button.icon-chart { background: url(http://dahlström.net/tmp/sharp-icons/svg-icon-target.svg#chart) no-repeat; }


img {
    width:  32px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 4px;
}
  </style>
  
</head>

<body> 
 <p>As background image</p>
<button class="icon-plus"></button>
<button class="icon-chart"></button>

<p> With img element</p>
<img src="http://dahlström.net/tmp/sharp-icons/svg-icon-target.svg#plus">
<img src="http://dahlström.net/tmp/sharp-icons//svg-icon-target.svg#chart">

</body>
</html>
```

**Добавление содержания файла svg целиком в css**

В этом случае  необходимо добавить `namespaces XML`

```
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
```

```css
div {
    width:  300px;
    height: 500px;
 background:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <path id='curvestroke' fill='red' stroke='black' stroke-width='4' d='M0,0 C100,70 500,50 0,500'></path></svg>");
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```